# How to add css classes to an installed app's form object in django

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, python-3.4, django-1.7

I am currently learning [django crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and incorporating them into my project. But I decided to use the [django-user-accounts](http://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle user profiles. The issue I am having is trying to style the provided forms. I referenced [pinax-theme-bootstrap](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap) to create the template and came up with this for most of the required templates:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <legend>Change password</legend>
    <fieldset>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

What would be the best method for adding css classes to the all the `<label>`s and the fields. What would be the best way to add classes to individual `<input>` tags? Is it possible to use crispy forms on a third party app like django-user-accounts?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to explicitly loop through the fields in the form, while listing the field and label separately and using a [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) to add css classes to a field.

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% for field in form %}     
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {% if not field.is_hidden %}
            <label for="{{field.id_for_label}}" class="col-lg-2">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% endif %}
        {{ field|add_class:"col-lg-8"}}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <p class="error">{{ field.errors }}</p>            
        {% endif %} 
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I could not find any solution for using django-crispy-forms.